# How to output a javascript file from a PHP file that can be referenced from a script include tag

Tags: javascript, php, caching

I am looking for a solution in PHP that will allow me to reference a PHP file that outputs javascript as a script includes in the header of my html page. The reason i'm looking to do this is because I have some dynamically generated javascript which I want the browser to cache.

I have done this before in ASP.NET by using a .ashx handler, but i'm not sure how to do it in PHP.

Here's a more detailed breakdown of what i'm trying to achieve.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascriptHandler.php"></script>
<head>
</head>
```

In the above example I want the `javascriptHandler.php` to respond with a javascript file once it's requested. 
The `javascriptHandler.php` needs to check the incoming request headers and determine whether the file already exists on the client and return the appropriate response.

I'm looking for any clean solution that will do what is described above or any links that will point me in the right direction. If there's a better way to include and cache dynamically generated javascript please post it here.

Comment: Why don't you just add some php code to that file? E.g. `<?php if( /* condition /* ) { ?> <script> //JAVASCRIPT </script> <?php } ?>`

Comment: I need the browser to cache the javascript. Currently the javascript is being referenced inline, but that is exactly what i'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Also if the javascript files gets requested after the page is already rendered, you'll need AJAX to do that.

Comment: The idea is that the javascriptHandler.php is requested exactly the same way a normal .js file is requested by the browser. Like i've said in my question, i've done this before with asp.net, but i could not find a PHP solution for this.

Comment: Your Code-Snippet is correct for your solution. Make sure you send the right Headers in your `javascriptHandler.php` (for cache-control and mime-type).

Comment: @RobSky Thanks, yes i'm trying to figure this out by applying the headers, but have not been able to get it right yet. Will keep on attempting  to get it done that way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Put JavaScript Headers in PHP file

Keep your HTML page the same. Call it as a `.php` file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascriptHandler.php"></script>
```

In your `javascriptHandler.php` file, add this to the very top of the file:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=604800, public");
?>
```

Then you can put your regular javascript below.  All together it will look like:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=604800, public");
?>

function bob(){
    alert('hello')
}
bob();
```

and your browser will treat your `javascriptHandler.php` file like a JavaScript resource. Normal caching rules will apply.

Answer (score 5):

### URL Rewrites on the web server:

This will rewrite the requested `.js` filename to read your `.php` file instead.

This is known as an 'Internal' Rewrite so the web-browser will not know the file is actually `.php`. It will believe it is the `.js` file it requested.

***Apache***

If you are using an `Apache` webserver, you can make an `.htaccess` file in the same directory as your `javascriptHandler.php` file.

Inside `.htaccess`, put the following:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    javascriptHandler.js$  javascriptHandler.php [PT]
```

***Nginx***

You can do this with an `Nginx` web-server also, but you have to do it inside of your `/etc/nginx/sites-available/yoursite` config file for your server.

I am not going into **how** to do rewrites on `Nginx` because it is much more complicated than `Apache`.  But it is basically the following:

```
server{rewrite javascriptHandler.js$  javascriptHandler.php last;}
```

---

### Just to Mention it

After these changes, you will call the file in your HTML page as you would normally in order to cache it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascriptHandler.js"></script>
```

On your webserver, you will save the file as `.php`.  This will allow you to use PHP to build dynamic JavaScript within the file.

```
/path/to/javascriptHandler.php
```

Comment: Thanks, gave you an upvote as i can see this as a potential solution. I'm trying to achieve this without having to modify the .htaccess, but i'll give this a shot if it does not work out.

Comment: @Jako Basson, I appreciate it.  There's also the second answer above/below this one that lets you avoid messing with `.htaccess`