# RewriteRule 123456.js for js.php?arg=123456

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, get

I basically need this: [How to make certain javascript files render from php using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944731/how-to-make-certain-javascript-files-render-from-php-using-htaccess)

...but with a $_GET argument inside my PHP script from the rewritten .js filename

So:

`http://localhost/123456.js`

...would be rewritten to make this work as normal:

`http://localhost/js.php?arg=123456`

...where `123456` could be anything...

...in a .php file that returns what SEEMS to the web to be a .js file, like this...

`js.php` contents:

```
<?php
$arg = $_GET['arg']
echo "loadCSS(\"$arg.css\");"
?>
```

...hoping to use this to embed the .js path in something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/123456.js"></script>
```

1. What should go in `.htaccess`?
2. Should anything else be different in my PHP script or elsewhere?

---

This didn't help either: [How to output a javascript file from a PHP file that can be referenced from a script include tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805355/how-to-output-a-javascript-file-from-a-php-file-that-can-be-referenced-from-a-sc/28806711)

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are sooo many examples of HTTPd rewriting of this kind (including in the first SO post you linked to) on SO.

Comment: I tried both of these, along with many others, some tutorials and kept searching but found nothing to convert the base filename into a $_GET variable specifically.

Comment: The first link you posted had an answer that did exactly that though...

Comment: ...okay, maybe. But, then it should be removed as not answering the non-$_GET question and, it was dependent on a domain. I will consider it, but it wasn't this accepted answer and wasn't what I needed like this answer was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # if the request file doesn't exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # and isn't a dir
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.js$ /js.php?arg=$1 [L]
```

Your php script should work. For beginners of mod_rewrite I recommend this tool: https://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

Comment: I had to change `/js.php?arg=$1` to `js.php?arg=$1` for it to work. And, on my local desktop Ubuntu dev server, REQUEST_FILENAME lines would break my server IF I use them with any other RewriteRules.